# Separator in typeahead menu?

Tags: typeahead.js

I am not sure if we already have a way of displaying a seprator in the typeahead menu using a single data source. I tried multiple combinations, tried searching around for a solution, but cannot get any.

More like in the screenshot below, I have this data from single source as:

```
['US: channel1', 'US: channel2', 'US: channel3', 'US: channel4', 'US: channel5', 'CA: channel1', 'CA: channel2']
```

In the data above, I want to show a separator after US based channels and then show the CA channel options.

[image]

I can update the data source to multi-dimenational array or any other customization, if required for showing a separator. Or, any other way outside the scope of typeaheadjs.

Please help me find one working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, I am going to answer my question. This is how did.

I had inserted a blank value which is to be replaced as separator.

```
['US: channel1', 'US: channel2', 'US: channel3', 'US: channel4', 'US: channel5', '', 'CA: channel1', 'CA: channel2']
```

To insert a blank data, we might have to use multi-dimensional array froma single data source.

And, using the `typeahead:render` event of typeaheadjs, I had to handle as shown below:

```
 $(input).bind('typeahead:render', function (e) {
     var currentInput = $(e.target),
         options;

    options = $(currentInput).closest('.column-filter').find('.tt-suggestion');
    $(options).each(function (index, element) {
        if (!$(element).text().trim().length) {
            $(element).replaceWith('<hr>');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bijoyanupam/gzt8dLcj/) with a working example.